# Airplane problem question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, simulation

I'm practicing some exercises for probability and counting and I came across this problem:

A small 100 seat theatre is conducting a play, and assigns a random seat number (from 1–100) to the ticketed guests right before they walk in. There are 36 guests in total, who usually sit in their assigned seats. If their seats are occupied for some reason, they choose another seat at random. An actor who is part of the play messes this up by picking a seat out of the 100 seats randomly (prior to any audience member arriving), possibly taking a ticketed audience's numbered seat.

The questions asked were:
***What is the probability that the last person is in the wrong seat?*** and ***On average, approximately how many people will sit in the wrong seat?***

I understand that this is very similar to the airplane probability problem but I was wondering if the same intuition should be used here as well?

Comment: "I understand that this is very similar to the airplane probability problem" ... could you explain the airplane problem? Are there references to this?

Comment: "An actor who is part of the play messes this up" what is the point of this? Did the guests got their tickets without overlap (selecting 36 tickets from the 100 *without* repetitiion) and the actor is what's messing it up?

Comment: This might be a useful link https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1161

Comment: You can compute this by first placing all guests, and then play the chair dance by adding the actor.

 - So the actor has a 36/100 probability of kicking out another person.
 - That person will sit somewhere else at random (on any of the other remaining 99 chairs) and has a 35/99 probability to kick out another person. 
 - That person, in case it happens, will sit somewhere else and kick out another person with a 34/98 probability. 
 - And so on.

Comment: You can view this also as an urn problem, in which an urn is filled with 36 red marbles and 64 blue marbles and you keep picking marbles until you get a blue marble. Then the question is how many red marbles you picked before you got a blue marble. 

The distribution can be written as

Comment: $$P(\text{$k$ seats displaced}) = P(\text{$k$ red}) = \underbrace{\frac{64}{100-k}}_{{\substack{\text{probability} \\ \text{blue marble} \\ \text{ after $k$ red}}}}\underbrace{\frac{36}{100} \cdot \frac{35}{99} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{36-k+1}{100-k+1}}_{{\substack{\text{probability} \\ \text{$k$ red marbles} }}} = \frac{64 \cdot 36!}{100!} \frac{(100-k-1)!}{(36-k)!} $$

Comment: > On average, approximately how many people will sit in the wrong seat?

You can compute the expectation value of the above.

> What is the probability that the last person is in the wrong seat?

The probability for the last guest to be in the wrong seat relates to average occupation of wrong seats for the 35 guests + actor in wrong seats (which could be the seat of the last guest).

This you can compute by generalizing the formula above for different numbers of guests.

Comment: I place these as comments because I hvd the answer already written just before it got closed. I waited a bit for opening, but I guess that will take a while, and I do not want to loose the answer (SE only remembers on answer while being edited).